# EMR Serverless JDK in custom image

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr-serverless

I wanted to run spark application built using JDK 11 on EMR Serverless. Since the default image does not have support of JDK 11, I created the custom image based on following links:

Use case 2 : https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/big-data/add-your-own-libraries-and-application-dependencies-to-spark-and-hive-on-amazon-emr-serverless-with-custom-images/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/using-custom-images.html

This is the content of my DockerFile ( I have M1 Mac)

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/emr-serverless/spark/emr-6.9.0:latest
USER root
# install JDK 11
RUN sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
# EMRS will run the image as hadoop
USER hadoop:hadoop
```

After uploading the image on ECR, I created the EMR Serverless application (x86_64) using the same custom image. Next I tried submitting the job with my jar built with JDK 11, however, it failed with following error:

```
The job run failed to be submitted to the application or it completed unsuccessfully.
```

Then, as per the above mentioned second link, I tried giving these two spark configuration while configuring the job:

```
--conf spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 
--conf spark.driverEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
```

I am still getting the below error:

```
Job failed, please check complete logs in configured logging destination. ExitCode: 1. Last few exceptions: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: <ClassName> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0\nException in thread \"main\" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: <ClassName> has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0...
```

Am I missing any step?

Regards Tapan

Comment: Issue is resolved: https://repost.aws/questions/QU-LEd1uM2Rr2p82ZNOvv9xg/emr-serverless-custom-image-not-running